# Plasma Physics emissivity

Tags: plasma-physics

When doing research in plasma physics. The emissivity of plasma is usually less than 1. Why is it important to measure the plasma emissivity?

Comment: So you know how to calibrate temperature of the plasma from measuring emission spectrum?

Comment: An emissivity of greater than 1 would be rather unusual...